# Can I recover deleted viber messages after my phone is erased?

Tags: iphone, recovery

My device is Iphone 6, I had deleted some messages from my viber, then I erased my phone 2 days after that, then I noticed there was information I need. I don't have back up of any sort.

can I somehow recover those messages? if yes how likely?

Comment: Data from a wiped iPhone is generally considered irrecoverable, other than by extremely interested government agencies, in case of terrorism etc.

Answer (score -1):

No.  Unless you have friends at NSA AND Apple.